# Using break; in Struts1 <logic:iterate>

Tags: java, apache, struts, struts-1

I am using Struts 1.2 for my Web Application. I am iterating through a garments collection and searching whether any of the garments price is greater than $1000 or not. If any of them satisfies the condition then no need to iterate through the remaining garments collection, simple break and come out of the iterator.

For comparing the price, I am using , it is present inside the .

I am not able to break out from the  once the garment price condition is satisfied (i.e. >$1000).

Kindly let me know how to break the iteration in struts 1.2.

Regards,

Comment: I don't believe the iterate tag supports this.  Can you perform the conditional logic in the action instead?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that it is not possible with iterate. Conditional Logic? what kind of logic you are talking about? Can you provide a little detailed information on that?

Comment: Why are you doing this on the display side? Seems *much* more reasonable to put this logic in a service/action/etc. and remove such decision making from the view.

Comment: For example, if you are using a ForwardAction to get to your page, change the struts-config.xml to use an Action you Define (e.g. ListGarmetsAction).  Assemble the collection in the execute method to contain only what you want to display on your jsp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struts 1 does not have any `in-built` tag for breaking the `<logic:iterator>` in between.